# Raspberry Pi Zero W start script on startup

Tags: camera, raspberry-pi, autostart

I'm creating a time-lapse camera to attach to a pair of glasses.

I tried out my script (python 3) and it works, but I need to get my script to work upon startup up since it will powered by a powerbank and I can't manually start the script because of that. (filename is "GlassCam.py" in the folder named "GlassCam")

This is what I've tried in the command line:

```
sudo nano ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

then in the menu

```
sudo /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/GlassCam/GlassCam.py
```

(control+x and then y to save)

yet it won't start when I reboot it or shut it down and plug it back in

Comment: It's possible that when you add a line to `~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`, you need to put a `@` at the start

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a cron job: `sudo crontab -e` and then add your script at the end of the file (to be executed on reboot) like this: `@reboot python /home/pi/GlassCam/GlassCam.py &`